# How to combine Session and API authentication in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

I have a simple project that has only 3 tables. The `users`, `table2`, and `table3`.

**The User schema**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->bigIncrements('id');
  $table->string('username')->unique();
  $table->string('password');
  $table->string('api_token')->unique();
  $table->rememberToken();
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

The other 2 tables are accessible via API resource.

Here are my routes:

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'Auth\LoginController@showLogin')->name('login');
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
//Authenticated users will be redirected here
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

**routes/api.php**

```
Route::resource('/table1', 'Table1Controller');
Route::resource('/table2', 'Table2Controller');
```

I've added the `auth:api` middleware in the `Table1Controller` and `Table2Controller`.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:api');
}
```

So I only have 2 pages to be exact. The main page where the authenticated user goes to and the login page.

When a user is added, it also saves a random string `api_token` to it's row.

I am using VueJS and I don't want to make a mess and use Node with this one. So I've downloaded the `vue.min.js` and just include it in my `blade` files.

So when you login, you will be redirected to `/home` page. The layout page of my pages has this one:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/vue.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/axios.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
const user = @json(Auth::user());

const http = axios.create({
  baseURL: '/api',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': user ? 'Bearer ' + user.api_token : ''
  }
});
</script>
```

With the code above, you should be able to access the table1 and table2 apis when you send a request.

Now I know I could've just used webpack and make my app a SPA and just use passport or maybe just jwt. But I don't want since it's a very simple app and I want to do actions without refreshing my pages like adding data in table, editing data and show it in a modal, etc.

By the way, this app will be used by the same app only. No other services will access it. I just want to use Vue for reactiveness and avoid full page reloads.

Is there a better way of doing this that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Auth facade if the user email and pass matches in your database just simply create a session of Auth.

```
Auth::user();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something called JWT, or JSON Web Tokens.

There is a laravel module available which I've used personally and it works well:

https://packagist.org/packages/tymon/jwt-auth

It allows you to add a JWT auth guard pretty easily, which uses the `Authorization: Bearer xxx` header to authenticate the user. The `xxx` is the JSON web token here, and it is a long string that contains encrypted user information. It can be decrypted on the server side, which would then identify the user. More info can be found here:

https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ (note this is the `1.*` version of `tymon/jwt-auth`, which is currently the latest).

ALTERNATIVELY

you can also use the default laravel session handler, which uses a cookie.